# UDP server and multiple clients (1v1 game)

Tags: multithreading, networking

I'm trying to create an UDP server with two slots per new instance of the game and clients.

It has to be UDP cause of the game mechanics. I wrote this:

```
public class Server {

   private static HashSet<Integer> ports = new HashSet<Integer>(); // these     are player's IDs
   static ArrayList<InetAddress> addresses = new ArrayList<InetAddress>(); 
   public static boolean player1_active = false, player2_active = false;
   public static PlayerCredits p1, p2, temp;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   // The default port     
    int serverport = 8888;        


    DatagramSocket udpServerSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverport);        
        DatagramPacket sendpacket;
    System.out.println("Server started...\n");

    while(true)
    {

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];          


        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);


        udpServerSocket.receive(receivePacket);           


        String clientMessage = (new String(receivePacket.getData())).trim();


        System.out.println("Client Connected - Socket Address: " + receivePacket.getSocketAddress());
        System.out.println("Client message: \"" + clientMessage + "\"");          


        InetAddress clientIP = receivePacket.getAddress();           
                    addresses.add(clientIP);

        System.out.println("Client IP Address & Hostname: " + clientIP + ", " + clientIP.getHostName() + "\n");

        // Get the port number which the recieved connection came from
        int clientport = receivePacket.getPort();
        System.out.println("Adding "+clientport);
        ports.add(clientport);

        // Response message         
        String returnMessage = clientMessage.toUpperCase();          
        System.out.println(returnMessage);
        // Create an empty buffer/array of bytes to send back 
        byte[] sendData  = new byte[1024];




                    temp = new PlayerCredits(clientport, clientIP);

                    if(!player1_active){
                     p1 = new PlayerCredits(clientport, clientIP);
                     player1_active = true;
                    }

                    if(temp.port != p1.port && temp.ad != p1.ad)
                     if(!player2_active){
                        p2 = new PlayerCredits(clientport, clientIP);
                        player2_active = true;
                    }

                    DatagramPacket sendPacket;
                     if(p2 == null){
                         String awaiting = "WAITING FOR SECOND PLAYER";
                         sendData = awaiting.getBytes();
                          sendPacket= new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, p1.ad, p1.port); 
                            udpServerSocket.send(sendPacket);   
                     }
                         else{
                         String awaiting = "SECOND PLAYER INCOMING";
                         sendData = awaiting.getBytes();
                            if(p2!=null){
                            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, p2.ad, p2.port); 
                            udpServerSocket.send(sendPacket);   
                            }
                            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, p1.ad, p1.port); 
                            udpServerSocket.send(sendPacket);    
                     }

        }

}
public static class PlayerCredits{
    int port;
    InetAddress ad;
    public PlayerCredits(int p, InetAddress a){
        this.port = p;
        this.ad = a;
    }
}
```

For now I have two people connected - but as you will probably say - it's WRONG. I need to somehow implement every player on the Multisocket or something (or connect them via TCP and then listen on a new thread with a new datagram).

As I know, the best way is to create a listener server (TCP) on a main thread - accept connections and pass them to 'Player's constructors' and in Player's class make the whole fun.

If there is someone that could help and tell me, how it should be done like in 3 steps like (I don't need code):

1. Connection with TCP
2. Create new threads with players and listen on UDP
3. Start the game when 2 players are connected

Also, how to stop the 'third connection' and redirect it to a new game instance? (cause it's 1v1).

Comment: Not sure what exactly do you need. What is 'multisocket'? I suggest you edit your code and remove all non-relevant game mechanics. Just leave the socket code you have in place and provide pseudo-code of what you'd like to do.

Comment: The main problem is here that I don't know which things should be handled by TCP and which by UDP. The whole queue?

My conception is (Im writing this right now):
- in the main class use TCP to get their ports to a hashmap and ipaddresses
- when I have 2 players - open a game, pass their ip&port to the constructor
- in a 'game' class use UDP to make the whole game mechanic

I just don't know the way how this should be done in a case with 1v1 game (client<>server<>client) in real time. Just need a point - where to start.

Comment: Still not clear. What is your endgoal? What are you trying to achieve? Why UDP, why TCP? So far I have no clue what you need and why.

Comment: I am creating a 1v1 game which must be updated in real-time - it's a fighting game.

Client one connects to a server and he's waiting for a client two. When client two connects - the game opens and the queue (server) is waiting for a new pair.

Stack says that mechanics (the whole game) must be handled by Datagrams (cause they're faster) and 'first connections' and 'queue' by TCP.

What am I trying to achieve:

I don't know if this above is true - cause if yes - I will try to write this queuing on TCP. If not - I will try to find another method.

Comment: Ok, first things first. By no means UDP is 'faster' than TCP. They just serve different purpose. UDP is a message protocol - it works best when peers communicate with each other in a form of encapsulated messages. TCP is stream-oriented protocol - it works best when peers maintain a communication channel between each other and send data to each other. A very loose analogy would be a phone conversation (TCP) vs. email (UDP). With phone conversation, you have two persons continuosly talking to each other. With email, you have one sending a message to another. You can't say which is faster.

Comment: I do not understand your notion of queue either.

Comment: Okay so for example:
Messages like: You won, Connecting to the server, please wait, blah blah - TCP
Things like: updating player's position on the server and opponent's screen, changing health, checking conditions like 'if p1 can attack p2' - UDP

Is this right?

If yes - should the whole queuing be made on TCP? I mean - the main thread that wait for players and pass them the the game?

Comment: Sorry, you are not making any sense. I can't help you.